# Length of a triangle side proportional to angle size?

Tags: triangles, angle

I'm trying to find the values of a and b in the following situation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxavX.jpg

I can get the correct answer using trigonometry, but I was wondering why the following solution does not give a correct result:

$$ a = 15 * \frac{35}{38+35}$$
$$ b = 15 * \frac{38}{38+35}$$

Is it because the length of the side of a triangle (a, b) isn't directly proportional to the angle (35°, 38°)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. Considering an extreme case, if one angle were $90º$, $a$ would be infinitely long whereas the incorrect method would be a fraction of $15$.

$a$ and $b$ are correctly related to each other by the extended [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem), which works even if the triangles are not right-angled. In your case, this would be:

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{x \sin 35º}{y \sin 38º}$$

but this is not the right method unless you know $x,y$ beforehand.

For this question, you would need to equate the common side as follows: $\frac{a}{\tan 35º} = \frac{b}{\tan 38º}$, which I presume is what you did. Finding one variable in terms of the other and using the fact that $a+b=15$ gives you $a,b$.

Comment: You don't even need to know $x$ and $y$ if you can use tangent instead.

Comment: That's very true.